# How to check if an amount is stacked on contract more than a one days

Tags: timestamp, datetime

I have following struct on my contract :

```
 struct Token {
        address tokenAddress;
        uint256 stakedAmount;
        bool isUsed;
        uint256 lastTransactionDate;
    }
```

It is used on following mapping :

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => Token)) public _stakingUserBalance
```

Each time user is stacking, I update `stakedAmount` with an amount and `lastTransactionDate` with `block.timestamp`.

In order to compute rewards, I need to know if stacking is more than 1 day.
But I'm not sure to understand correctly unix timestamp process.

Is it a way to convert `lastTransactionDate` to a readable date, and compare with the moment of computing reward ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, solved it with a function that refreshes time limit to zero if conditions are met.

First you need to create your own constant variable DAY,

```
uint constant DAY = 60 * 60 * 24; // Number of seconds in a day

 /**
 * Refreshes the transfer limit of the given address if it has been more than 24h since it last sent funds.
 */
function refreshTimeLimit(address addr, address tokenAddress) public {
    if (block.timestamp - _stakingUserBalance[addr].Token[tokenAddress].transactionTime > DAY) {
        _stakingUserBalance[addr].Token[tokenAddress].lastTransactionDate = block.timestamp;
        _stakingUserBalance[addr].Token[tokenAddress].stakedAmount = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the time/date of the last transaction from this address.
 */
function transactionTime(address addr, address tokenAddress) public view returns (uint){
    return  _stakingUserBalance[addr].Token[tokenAddress].lastTransactionDate;
}

/**
 * Returns the amount that had been stacked from the address in the last 24h.
 */
function stakedSum(address addr, address tokenAddress) public view returns (uint){
    return _stakingUserBalance[addr].Token[tokenAddress].stakedAmount;
}
```

Comment: Note: my mapping had been different, and I didn't had time to fully edit the code. But the concept is there.